# Implementing call-by-value lambda-calculus in Haskell

Tags: haskell, interpreter, lambda-calculus

When implementing call-by-value lambda-calculus in Haskell, should I force the evaluation of the arguments to a function in the object language (i.e., the call-by-value lambda-calculus) to get around the call-by-need evaluation order of the meta-language (i.e., Haskell)?

Concretely, for the following implementation using higher-order abstract syntax:

```
data Exp
  = Abs (Exp -> Exp)
  | App Exp Exp

eval :: Exp -> Exp
eval exp = case exp of
  Abs _       -> exp
  App opr opd -> case eval opr of
    Abs fun -> eval (fun $ eval opd)  -- argument evaluation
```

on the line with comment, should I force the evaluation of `eval opd` by using `fun $! eval opd` instead?

I am aware that the evaluation order dependence between the object and meta- level can be avoid by CPS transformation.  But I do not wanna bother it for the moment.  I just wanna
make sure that call-by-value is implemented faithfully in Haskell.  I raised this question because many example implementations I have seen seem not to take this into account.  I mean
those implementations do not force `eval opd`.  I wonder whether it is that they neglect it or that I consider too much.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `$!` does work here, as long as evaluating `eval e` to weak head normal form in the meta-language corresponds to evaluating `e` to a value in the object language.

Let me demonstrate that by adding a new constructor to the `Exp` data type to represent a diverging computation, and a value that we can actually print:

```
data Exp
  = Abs (Exp -> Exp)
  | App Exp Exp
  | Bot
  | Value

printExp :: Exp -> String
printExp Bot = "bottom"
printExp Value = "base value"
printExp (Abs _) = "function"
printExp (App _ _) = "thunk"
```

For simplicity, let’s just transform it to a call to `error` in the evaluation function.

```
eval :: Exp -> Exp
eval exp = case exp of
  Bot         -> error "Evaluation would not terminate "
  Value       -> Value
  Abs _       -> exp
  App opr opd -> case eval opr of
    Abs fun -> eval (fun $ eval opd)
```

Now we can see if this is call-by-value. The following code should diverge, as we are passing bottom to a function. Alas, it does not:

```
*Main> let e = App (Abs (\_ -> Value)) Bot
*Main> printExp e
"thunk"
*Main> printExp (eval e)
"base value"
```

Does it help to change `$` to `$!`? Yes, it does:

```
*Main> let e = App (Abs (const Value)) Bot
*Main> printExp (eval e)
"*** Exception: Evaluation would not terminate
```

But how reliable is that? Any change to the `Exp` datatype has to be carefully checked to see if forcing the outermost constructor is what you want, e.g. introduction of pairs.

It might be a bit more reliable to use `deepseq`, i.e. `$!!`. But what I would really suggest is to add a `isValue :: Exp -> Bool` predicate that explicitly checks if the argument is a base value of your object language, and check `isValue (eval opd)` in `eval` before calling `fun`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion.  So the matter I am worried about does exist and most people just neglect it.  How unfortunate it is!

Comment: Do you actually have references where people rely on `seq` in an interpreter to obtain call-by-value semantics?

Comment: It seems you misunderstood me.  I noticed people do not use it when they present example implementations for the (intended) call-by-value lambda calculus.  Since they neither use it nor use an `isValue` predicate as you suggested, I think their implementation is not faithful.

Comment: @plmday - I'm not a theorist, but I believe if you didn't use HOAS you wouldn't need `seq` to get CBV semantics. It's because you are using HOAS (and so Haskell's semantics for application) that you are forced to deal with "forcing".

Comment: @stephentetley: Thanks for the comment.  I think even if we do not use HOAS, we still need a force evaluation of the argument.  Suppose we use closures, the case for application must be: `App opr opd -> case eval opr denv of { Clo var bod senv -> eval bod $ extend var (eval opd denv) senv }`, where evaluation has reached the function body before `eval opd denv` gets evaluated.